# IRC related help

Tags: php, irc

Now I have my bot to send message when the bot joins. However how do I make a form that would post data so that the bot will say the message to the channel?

Here is my script (Rewamped):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

$socket = fsockopen("//", 6667) or die();

$msg = $_POST['message'];
$pr = $_POST['percentage'];
$pr /= 100;

fputs($socket,"USER BOT 0 zo :ZH bot\n");
// Set the bots nickname
fputs($socket,"NICK BOT1\n");

fputs($socket,"JOIN #bots\n");

while(1) {

   while($data = fgets($socket, 128)) {
      // echo the data received to page
      echo nl2br($data);
      // flush old data, it isn't needed any longer.
      flush();

      $ex = explode(' ', $data);

      if($ex[0] == "PING") fputs($socket, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n");

      $search_string = "/^:([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)[@!~a-zA-Z0-9@\.\-]+\s*([A-Z]+)\s*[:]*([\#a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\s*[:]*([!\#\-\.A-Za-z0-9 ]+)*/";

      $do = preg_match($search_string, $data, $matches);

      // check that there is a command received
      if(isset($matches['2'])) {
         switch($matches['2']) {
            case "PRIVMSG":
               $user = $matches['1'];
               $channel = $matches['3'];
               $chat_text = isset($matches['4']) ? $matches['4'] : "";

               // check chat for !time
               if(strtolower($chat_text) == "!time") { 
                  $output = "::::: " . date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . " :::::";
                  fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG " . $channel . " :" . $output . "\n");
               } elseif(strtolower($chat_text) == "!hello") {
                  fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG " . $channel . " :Hello!\n");
               }
            break;

            case "JOIN":
               $user = $matches['1'];
               $channel = $matches['3'];
               fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG " . $channel . " :Welcome " . $user . " to " . $channel . "\n");
            break;
         }

      }
   }
}
?>
```

E.g. Making a form that would send the data to the IRC channel. The output would be "wget file info port" <-- That would be the text sent to the IRC channel.

Here are parts related:

```
fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG " . $channel . " :Welcome " . $user . " to " . $channel ."\n");
```

Hope someone can help out.

Comment: So what you're looking for is while the bot is being run, you can have a form on a web server that users can submit data to, and the bot spits out some formatted information to the IRC channel, correct?

Comment: Basically, A simple form that sends a command to the IRC main channel. E.g. Form = Host + Time + Submit button. If I enter 127.0.0.1 as host and time as 100. The out put on the IRC main channel would be 127.0.0.1 100 <--.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay here's a better answer. The first section still stands. A new PHP process is called every time you want to initiate a new script. Thus, you need some way to do IPC.

Here's how it's done on *nix (but not windows) in PHP:

**Receiver:**

```
<?php
$queueKey = 123321;

$queue = false;
if(msg_queue_exists($queueKey)) {
        echo "Queue Exists.\n";
}

// Join the queue
$queue = msg_get_queue($queueKey);

while(!($queue == false)) {
        // Note: This function could block if you feel like threading
        $msgRec = msg_receive(
                $queue,        // I: Queue to get messages from
                0,             // I: Message type (0 = first on queue)
                $msgType,      // O: Type of message received
                1024,          // I: Max message size
                $msgData,      // O: Data in the message
                true,          // I: Unserialize data
                MSG_IPC_NOWAIT // I: Don't block
        );

        if($msgRec) {
                echo "Message received:\n";
                echo "Type = $msgType\n";
                echo "Data = \n";
                print_r($msgData);
        }
}
?>
```

**Sender:**

```
<?php
$queueKey = 123321;

$queue = false;
if(msg_queue_exists($queueKey)) {
        echo "Queue Exists.\n";
} else {
        echo "WARNING: Queue does not exist. Maybe no listeners?\n";
}

$queue = msg_get_queue($queueKey);

$abc["something"] = "something value";
$abc["hello"] = "world";
$abc["fu"] = "bar";
msg_send(
        $queue, // Queue to send on
        1,      // Message type
        $abc,   // Data to send
        true,   // Serialize data?
        true    // Block
);

?>
```

This should produce (in the receiver loop) something similar to this:

```
Message received:
Type = 1 
Data =
Array 
(
    [something] => something value
    [hello] => world
    [fu] => bar 
)
```

Your script might look something like this

postToMe.php:

```
<?php
$queueKey = 123321;

$queue = false;
if(msg_queue_exists($queueKey)) {
        echo "Queue Exists.\n";
} else {
        echo "WARNING: Queue does not exist. Maybe no listeners?\n";
}

$queue = msg_get_queue($queueKey);

msg_send(
        $queue, // Queue to send on
        1,      // Message type
        $_POST, // Data to send
        true,   // Serialize data?
        true    // Block
);

?>
```

bot.php:

```
<?php 
set_time_limit(0); 

$socket = fsockopen("//", 6667) or die(); 

$msg = $_POST['message']; 
$pr = $_POST['percentage']; 
$pr /= 100; 

fputs($socket,"USER BOT 0 zo :ZH bot\n"); 
// Set the bots nickname 
fputs($socket,"NICK BOT1\n"); 

fputs($socket,"JOIN #bots\n"); 


$queueKey = 123321;
$queue = false;

// Join the IPC queue
$queue = msg_get_queue($queueKey);
if(!$queue) echo "ERROR: Could not join IPC queue. Form data will not be received";

while(1) { 
   // Handle new post info
   // You may want to increase the message size from 1024 if post data is large
   if(msg_receive($queue, 0, $msgType, 1024, $msgData, true, MSG_IPC_NOWAIT)) {
      // Handle data here. Post data is stored in $msgData
   }

   while($data = fgets($socket, 128)) { 
      // echo the data received to page 
      echo nl2br($data); 
      // flush old data, it isn't needed any longer. 
      flush(); 

      $ex = explode(' ', $data); 

      if($ex[0] == "PING") fputs($socket, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n"); 

      $search_string = "/^:([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)[@!~a-zA-Z0-9@\.\-]+\s*([A-Z]+)\s*[:]*([\#a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\s*[:]*([!\#\-\.A-Za-z0-9 ]+)*/"; 

      $do = preg_match($search_string, $data, $matches); 

      // check that there is a command received 
      if(isset($matches['2'])) { 
         switch($matches['2']) { 
            case "PRIVMSG": 
               $user = $matches['1']; 
               $channel = $matches['3']; 
               $chat_text = isset($matches['4']) ? $matches['4'] : ""; 

               // check chat for !time 
               if(strtolower($chat_text) == "!time") {  
                  $output = "::::: " . date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . " :::::"; 
                  fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG " . $channel . " :" . $output . "\n"); 
               } elseif(strtolower($chat_text) == "!hello") { 
                  fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG " . $channel . " :Hello!\n"); 
               } 
            break; 

            case "JOIN": 
               $user = $matches['1']; 
               $channel = $matches['3']; 
               fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG " . $channel . " :Welcome " . $user . " to " . $channel . "\n"); 
            break; 
         } 

      } 
   } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Can you convert that to simple php, I don't need it to advanced. Basic form and somthing that sends the command to the irc main channel.

Comment: That is as basic as it gets. If you use $_POST as your data to be sent to the bot and put the receiver somewhere in the while loop to process it, then your receiver will get all the post data from your form.

Comment: I've just added more specific instructions relating to your script. This is definutely as simple as I can possibly make it. That said, I havn't run it through an interpreter, sooooo it might throw up an error. But I've been over it a bit; it should work!

Comment: Thanks, can you edit the last part where when I post data the PRIVMSG should get the data and send back to the main IRC chan? If you can do that part I can do the form and etc. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this script will be running all the time. The way PHP works is that for each script that is being run, a new PHP process is created. Scripts can be run multiple times simultaneously, however they will not be able to directly communicate.

You will need to create enother script (or at least a whole new function of this one) to accept the post variables, and then send them to the running version of this script.

(Note: I will provide 2 solutions, since 1 is significantly more difficult. Also, there's Semaphore that I've just found, however I am unsure exactly if this suits our needs because I know next to nothing about it http://php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php)

**Best (But Advanced)**

The *best* way I can think of doing this would be to use sockets (particularly on *nix, since sockets are fantastic for IPC [inter process communication]). It's a little difficult, since you're basically create a client/server just to communicate details, then you need to come up with some sort of a protocol for your IPC.

I won't code anything up here, but the links that are relevant to this are
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-listen.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-accept.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php

If using this on *nix, I would highly recommend using AF_UNIX as the domain. It's very efficient, and quite a number of applications use it for IPC.

Pros:
Very robust solution

- Highly efficient
- Instant (or as close as we can get) communication

Cons:

- Quite difficult to implement

**Not As Great (But Still Good)**

Just use files to communicate the information. Have your bot script check the file every 15 seconds for changes. I would suggest using XML for the data (since simple xml makes xml processing in php well... simple)

Things you need to consider would be:
How would it react when receiving 2 posts at the same time? (If you just use a flat file or don't account for having multiple entries, this will become a problem).
How you find out if a message is new (I'd delete/blank the file right after reading. Note: Not after processing, as someone could post to the form script while you are processing/sending the message)

Links:
How to use simple xml
http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

File related
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

With that being said, you could also use MySQL/Postgres or some other database back end to deal with the flow of data between scripts.

Pros:

- Easy to implement

Cons:

- Slow to transfer data (checks files at given intervals)
- Uses external files, which can be deleted/modified my external applications/users

Comment: Even the file part? You will need to exchange information between 2 scripts somehow. A file is the simplest way I can think of. The sockets are advanced, but files should be fairly simple.

Comment: I only need the PHP script to send a command to the IRC channel. A basic form + submit button.

Comment: Basically, A simple form that sends a command to the IRC main channel. E.g. Form = Host + Time + Submit button. If I enter 127.0.0.1 as host and time as 100. The out put on the IRC main channel would be 127.0.0.1 100 <--.

Comment: Yes, but you can't accept data from the post in your main script. When you post new data, PHP fires up a new process and thus you need a way to get the data from your script that accepts the post to your script that sends the IRC message. Unless of course you have the bot only join when a new message is posted (in which case you would need to open irc socket, connect, send message, disconnect, close irc socket)

Comment: That being said, I am making the assumption (given the while loop) that you are wanting your bot script to be running 24/7 and not only when someone posts a message.

Comment: Also yeah, probaly I will leave the bot to finish sending the command and letting next bot join I can simply use ignore_abort(true); for that. It would be simply a form sending command to the irc channel. I don't need the bot to stay alive constantly it can quit and join.